# How to display all the all the child/parent nodes of the given node of fully nested hierarchy in arangodb

Tags: arangodb

We have an edge collection "ChildEvents" with 999999 records

Structure:

_from:events/1, _to: events/2

_from:events/2, _to: events/3

In this structure node-1 is super parent, and node-2 is child of node-1, and node-3 is child of 2. ( Nested hierarchy from top to bottom)

1-->2-->3-->4-->....999999

My requirement is to display all the nested parent/or children of the given node.
Eg. If i provide node - 4, the query should display the children from the node-5 to node-999999.
 **(I had this in neo4J databse working using a match query).**

But in arangoDB when i tried to achieve this using the below query,its returning only 2 records.

****FOR v IN OUTBOUND "events/350" any ChildEvents RETURN v****

Could some one help on this? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traversal queries require that you declare a `min` value ("0" in my example), but to satisfy your requirements, you need to declare a `max` value (999999) as well (see docs [here](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/graphs-traversals.html#working-with-collection-sets)).

Also, the term `any` is not used in this fashion, especially since you are looking for outbound relations (outbound ***from*** the parent ***to*** a child).

```
FOR v IN 0..999999 OUTBOUND 'events/350'
    ChildEvents
    RETURN v
```

1. Finds node with `_key` = '350' from the 'events' collection
2. Returns the start node ('events/350')
3. Returns all child nodes of 'events/350' (all 999,648 of them)

You do not need to provide an exact number for the "max" value - this is simply an upper limit on the number of edges to traverse.

If this query does not work for you, then I suggest taking a close look at your edges.  You might either have a gap or an incorrect direction (swapped `_from` & `_to`).

Comment: Thanks Kerry. So having upper limit makes my query working, but i feel this imposes some limitations. If the events are dynamically generated and if we know upper limit ONLY at run time, its getting hard to get the result. If I compare neo4J product where i have 1 million nodes all i need to do this query - MATCH({id:1})-[*]-(connected)
RETURN connected which gives me all the parent and child nodes from connected nodes. So we dont have such equivalent in ArangoDB?

Comment: @SolaiSrinivasan, not that I am aware of.  I find the `limit` to be restrictive sometimes, but I understand why it's there.  That said, the limit does not need to match your actual upper bound.  Setting the `limit` to a very large number (something larger than the number of traversals you could encounter) makes it essentially limitless.